# syncronized readers and writers in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to implement my own `readWriteLock` class, without using the `readWriteLock` provided by the API.

i have this situation:

```
public void read(){
    if(!write){
    read = true;
   //any thread can enter here and read;
    ....
    read = false;
    }
}

 public syncrhonized void write(){
    if(!read){
         write = true;
         //only one thread at time can write.
         ....
         write = false;
   }
}
```

there are a lot of bad situations which can happen with this code, for example:

- if one thread enter inside `if(!read){...}` and immediately this become true so it can't write.
- if threads enter inside `if(!write){...}` and immediately this become true so they can't read.

i manage to use `atomicBoolean`, but this is a `mutex - exclusion` for all threads that at the same time want to read and this doesn't resolve the ambiguity.

can someone provide me an explanation?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Classic deadlock situation. To prevent this have a look into semaphores.

Comment: What's wrong with java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not a good idea. As you have already mentioned yourself, there is already an existing mechanism for that. Why reinventing the wheel?

If your really need your own implementation, to do it correctly many more synchronized blocks are needed. You need to synchronize getting and releasing read lock, you cannot only synchronize access to write method.

Example which I have not checked but looks fine. All credits to Jakob Jenkov (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html)

```
public class ReadWriteLock{

  private int readers       = 0;
  private int writers       = 0;
  private int writeRequests = 0;

  public synchronized void lockRead() throws InterruptedException{
    while(writers > 0 || writeRequests > 0){
      wait();
    }
    readers++;
  }

  public synchronized void unlockRead(){
    readers--;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized void lockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
    writeRequests++;

    while(readers > 0 || writers > 0){
      wait();
    }
    writeRequests--;
    writers++;
  }

  public synchronized void unlockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
    writers--;
    notifyAll();
  }
}
```